# Gephi graph disappeared after adding few more nodes and edges

Tags: gephi

I am quite new to Gephi, but after reading the [tutorials on the official page](https://gephi.org/users/) I manged to make a decent graph. However, after adding few more nodes and edges to the database (currently has 31 nodes and 45 edges -see below) and re-generating the graph from layout tab, the graph disappeared and the "Force Atlas" distribution won't stop loading. I tried with other layout distributions with same results and I also tried with the zoom to extents icon but nothing would show up.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening and how could I fix that?

I am attaching two csv files which contain an anonymized version of my nodes and edges:

- [Nodes.csv](http://pastebin.com/3Q8SVsAc)
- [Edges.csv](http://pastebin.com/S6cAwz3h)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a workaround in order to solve my problem: I ran the randomized layout (name may differ, as I am using a localized version), which results in a not so nice layout which fits in the screen (which is its main achievement). After that, I can run other distributions such as "Force Atlas" and nodes and edges would show up and fit on the screen.